# How to generate an array of strings based on a certain set of parameters?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to generate an array of strings (or any other data structure that might be more useful for my task, but I can't think of anything else) in Python.

The program I'm working on has several sets of radio buttons. For example a set of "Block"/"Alternate" and "Single"/"Duplicate".

Examples on how the array of strings should look when they are activated:

Block, Single:

`list = ['A', 'B', 'C', '1', '2', '3']`

Alternating, Single:

`list = ['A', '1', 'B', '2', 'C', '3']`

Alternating, Duplicate:

`list = ['A', 'A', '1', '1', 'B', 'B', '2', '2', 'C', 'C', '3', '3']`

Those are only several examples, the program has way more, but the concept is the same.

I need to read this array of strings and use it as a schema of sorts to further select some data from my Pandas Dataframe.

How would I go about generating this array without writing an if clause for every single possible combination?

Comment: Clarify your question. So, you need to create an array of strings; What's your roadblock? You never even asked a question.

Comment: I edited my question; I am not sure on how to write this without chaining if clauses or using if clauses for every possible combination

Comment: So if I understood well, you will always have an even list, never uneven ?

Comment: Seems like it. I'm thonking up a solution involving for loops.

Comment: Are you familiar with dictionaries? Also, approximately how many cases do you have?

Comment: Yes, of course I'm familiar with dictionaries, I just thought that using them wouldn't work since I might end up with duplicate keys, and decided against it.

So far I have three sets of checkboxes (two as listed above and one that changes whenever I have to start my list with letters or integers, translated to the example I gave here - so it can be 1,2,3,A,B,C depending on what's selected). Then I can manually specify how often every character can appear, so all of them can appear twice except one. That would make the list uneven

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve this using Jupyter Notebook and some widgets for the user interaction. I don' know how you get this informations but to replicate the same behaviour I am using this.

```py
In [1]:
import ipywidgets as widgets # Widgets for user interactions

## Change the list as you want
my_list = ['A', 'B', 'C', '1', '2', '3']

single_duplicate = widgets.ToggleButtons(
    description='Do you want to Duplicate the list ?',
    options=['Single', 'Duplicate'],
    value='Single',
    style={'description_width': 'initial'}
)
single_duplicate

Out [1]:
```

[image]

```py
In [2]:
block_alter = widgets.ToggleButtons(
    description='Do you want to Alternate the list?',
    options=['Block', 'Alternate'],
    value='Block',
    style={'description_width': 'initial'}
)

block_alter

Out [2]:
```

[image]

#### Then define the function to manipulate the list with the user input

```py
In [3]:
def get_array(single_duplicate, block_alter, my_list):
    temporary_list = []
    ## Answer to Single or Duplicate
    if single_duplicate == 'Duplicate':
        for elem in my_list:
            temporary_list.append(elem)
            temporary_list.append(elem)
    else:
        temporary_list = my_list
        
    ## Answer to Block or Aternate ?
    new_list = []
    if block_alter == 'Alternate':
        half = int(len(temporary_list)/2)
        for i in range(half):
            new_list.append(temporary_list[i])
            new_list.append(temporary_list[i + half])
    else:
        new_list = temporary_list
    return new_list
```

Use `get_array(single_duplicate.value, block_alter.value, my_list)` to see the output with the user's choses

#### Here some exemples

```py
In [3]:
print(get_array('Single', 'Block', my_list))
print(get_array('Duplicate', 'Block', my_list))
print(get_array('Single', 'Alternate', my_list))
print(get_array('Duplicate', 'Alternate', my_list))

Out [3]:
['A', 'B', 'C', '1', '2', '3']
['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', '1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3']
['A', '1', 'B', '2', 'C', '3']
['A', '1', 'A', '1', 'B', '2', 'B', '2', 'C', '3', 'C', '3']
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps me avoid at least several if clauses and looks pretty clean. I am using PyQt for my UI, but the idea's pretty clear, thanks!